# Delete video from server and database

Tags: php, filezilla

I have blog where you also can add images and videos. The problem I have is that when I'm deleting a blog the image or video will still be on the server and too much files on the server isn't good for the server. After some research I found the `unlink()` function. So I tried it but it does not work. the images won't delete from the server. It only deletes them of the database.

**What I tried**

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteSubcat'])){
  $del = $_POST['deleteSubcat'];
    DeleteSubCat($del);
}

function DeleteSubCat($del){
    include '../../../include/dbConnection/dbcon.php';

    //to skip the update query because the item is about to delete.
    $type = '1';
    // DeleteVideo($del, $type);

    //deletes subcat from tables hw_subcategorie.
    $sqldelete = 'DELETE FROM hw_subcategorie WHERE subcategorie_id = "'.$del.'"';
    //if query is done right then 'Record updated successfully'
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqldelete)) {
      $sqlimg = 'SELECT video_link FROM hw_subcategorie WHERE subcategorie_id = "'.$del.'"';
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlimg);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      unlink("video/".$row["video_link"]);
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error deleted record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you sure that path to `unlink()` is correct? It shows some error?

Comment: yes i pretty sure i can show you my folder structure

Comment: You're deleting and after you are searching for that `id` that was deleted

Comment: @dm707 i tried both ways but both wouldnt work.

Comment: So, provide your folder structure

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you missing an `if` statement around the `unlink` part (just counting braces here).

Comment: @Sjeiti i don't know much about `unlink` but is it necessary?

Comment: @Sjeiti it is only bad formatted

Comment: Ah right... Stackoverflow needs an autoformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to search a deleted record to delete the video from server.

Perform the select before delete:

```
function DeleteSubCat($del){
    include '../../../include/dbConnection/dbcon.php';

    //to skip the update query because the item is about to delete.
    $type = '1';

    // Get the video link before delete it from db
    $sqlimg = 'SELECT video_link FROM hw_subcategorie WHERE subcategorie_id = "'.$del.'"';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlimg);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $videoLink = $row["video_link"];
    unlink("video/".$videoLink);
    //deletes subcat from tables hw_subcategorie.
    $sqldelete = 'DELETE FROM hw_subcategorie WHERE subcategorie_id = "'.$del.'"';
    //if query is done right then 'Record updated successfully'
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqldelete)) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleted record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```